# add_rewrite_rule questions

Tags: php, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I've read several tutorials on the subject, but am not seeming to be making headway here.

Ultimately, I am trying to write the following url:

`example.com/parts/by_model/YEAR/MAKE/POST-NAME/#`

Where

Year = the 'vyear' custom taxonomy,

Make = the 'make' custom taxonomy,

Post Name = the post name

and # = post_id

Specifically, post name should not need to match. Ultimately, what I really care about is just fetching the correct custom post based on the # at the end of the url, and the rest of it doesn't really matter.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly?

```
function my_custom_rewrites() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'parts/by_model/%vyear%/%make%/([^/]*)/([0-9]{1,})/?$',
        'index.php?p=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'adsit_custom_rewrites' );
```

I can write a url correctly, for example: example.com/parts/by_model/1965/mercedes/1965-220b/209/

The number at the end is completely ignored, and you can change it to anything and it still gets the post based on the post name.

For reference, I already got wordpress to write the url for the taxonomy terms 'vyear' and 'make' by placing this in my functions.php

```
add_filter('post_link', 'my_model_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_model_permalink', 10, 3);

function my_model_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (((strpos($permalink, '%vyear%') === FALSE) && (strpos($permalink, '%make%') === FALSE)) || (strpos($permalink, '%vyear%') === FALSE) || (strpos($permalink, '%make%') === FALSE)) return $permalink;

    // Get post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post) return $permalink;

    // Get taxonomy terms
    $y_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'vyear');
    if (!is_wp_error($y_terms) && !empty($y_terms) && is_object($y_terms[0])) $y_taxonomy_slug = $y_terms[0]->slug;
    else $y_taxonomy_slug = 'other';

    $m_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'make');
    if (!is_wp_error($m_terms) && !empty($m_terms) && is_object($m_terms[0])) $m_taxonomy_slug = $m_terms[0]->slug;
    else $m_taxonomy_slug = 'other';

    return str_replace('%vyear%/%make%', $y_taxonomy_slug . '/' . $m_taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

and the rewrite rule for the custom post type is `parts/by_model/%vyear%/%make%`

Any idea here? I know I'm close, I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: Realized I forgot to flush the permalinks, which I just tried. The permalink is showing up in the Monkeyman Rewrite Analyizer, but it certainly isn't working as expected. Again, I can change the number to any value I want and it still pulls the page based on the rest of the information

Comment: Just one more thing on this, Analyzing this, I am getting the following output in wp debug bar for 'Matched Rewrite Rule' : ``parts/by_model/(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$``

Comment: One last comment before I give an update on this ... I've narrowed it down to the way the query string is being written. for example, using the url example.com/parts/by_model/1960/mercedes/1960-220seb/395/ gives the following query string upon inspection: `page=%2F395&make=mercedes&vyear=1960&vehicle=1960-220seb&post_type=vehicle&name=1960-220seb` .. in here, you can see that the page=%2F is what is concerning. it doesnt appear to be correctly escaping the '/' precedding the final value for some reason